# Replace existing response with new using servlet filter in spring mvc

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, servlets, filter

I want to replace exisiting `json` response(In some condition) with the new one using filters. What am trying to do is read existing response (`JSON`) from filter. Modify it with new values and write back to response. But the result shows both the response.

That is , what i have read from response and what i added newly. But i need to replace the old response with new. Code added below.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) 
{
    try{
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);

        chain.doFilter(request,new HttpServletResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse)response) {
               @Override
             public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
                return new DelegatingServletOutputStream(new TeeOutputStream(super.getOutputStream(), ps)
                );
             }
          @Override
             public  PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
                return new PrintWriter(new DelegatingServletOutputStream (new TeeOutputStream(super.getOutputStream(), ps))
                );
             }
          });
        /* get existing response as string*/
        String respopn=baos.toString(); 
        JSONObject json=new JSONObject(respopn);
        JSONObject dMap=new JSONObject(json.get("dataMap"));
        dMap.put("new", "newValue");
        json.put("dataMap", dMap); // Modified the old datamap with new json
        JsonMapper jsonMap=new JsonMapper();
        jsonMap.setJson(json);
        String str=jsonMap.getJson();
        byte[] responseToSend = restResponseBytes(jsonMap);
        response.getOutputStream().write(responseToSend); // write to response only the new one



    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }


   private byte[] restResponseBytes(Object response) throws IOException {
        String serialized = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(response);
        return serialized.getBytes();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736328/looking-for-an-example-for-inserting-content-into-the-response-using-a-servlet-f, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439260/replace-response-body-using-filter, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452318/how-to-alter-the-body-of-a-http-response-in-a-filter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel below code snippet should work.The problem with above is it is getting appended to the existing data instead of rewriting. We need to create a copy with where the data is stored and copy after manipulating to the original ServletResponse. Hope below code snippet solve your issue.

below is the main do filter method-

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    ServletResponseWrapperCopier capturingResponseWrapper = new ServletResponseWrapperCopier(
                (HttpServletResponse) response);

    chain.doFilter(request, capturingResponseWrapper);
    try{
        String respopn = capturingResponseWrapper.getCaptureAsString();     
        JSONObject json=new JSONObject(respopn);
        JSONObject dMap=new JSONObject(json.get("dataMap"));
        dMap.put("new", "newValue");
        json.put("dataMap", dMap); // Modified the old datamap with new json
        JsonMapper jsonMap=new JsonMapper();
        jsonMap.setJson(json);
        String str=jsonMap.getJson();
        response.getOutputStream().write(str.getBytes());
    } catch(Exception e){
        log.error("");
    }
}
```

Below class is used to copy the ServletResponse in the above code snippet

```
public class ServletResponseWrapperCopier extends HttpServletResponseWrapper{

private final ByteArrayOutputStream capture;
private ServletOutputStream output;
private PrintWriter writer;

public ServletResponseWrapperCopier(HttpServletResponse response) {
    super(response);
    capture = new ByteArrayOutputStream(response.getBufferSize());
}

@Override
public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() {
    if (writer != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "getWriter() has already been called on this response.");
    }

    if (output == null) {
        output = new ServletOutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                capture.write(b);
            }

            @Override
            public void flush() throws IOException {
                capture.flush();
            }

            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException {
                capture.close();
            }
        };
    }

    return output;
}

@Override
public PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
    if (output != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "getOutputStream() has already been called on this response.");
    }

    if (writer == null) {
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(capture,
                getCharacterEncoding()));
    }

    return writer;
}

public byte[] getCaptureAsBytes() throws IOException {
    if (writer != null) {
        writer.close();
    } else if (output != null) {
        output.close();
    }

    return capture.toByteArray();
}

public String getCaptureAsString() throws IOException {
    return new String(getCaptureAsBytes(), getCharacterEncoding());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could also be considered.
So first create a response wrapper. (add the content-type if needed or else you could leave as it is. Mine had a xhml content-type and that prompted me to change the content-type)

Next create wrappers for the printwriter and ServletOutputStream. The wrapper for servlet OutputStream is optional but that depends on you need. Here are the implementations

ByteArrayServletStream.java

```
public class ByteArrayServletStream extends ServletOutputStream {

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos;

    ByteArrayServletStream(ByteArrayOutputStream baos) {
        this.baos = baos;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int param) throws IOException {
        baos.write(param);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReady() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setWriteListener(WriteListener listener) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

ByteArrayPrinter.java

```
/**
 * IMplemented own Printer as the new wrapper
 *
 */
public class ByteArrayPrinter {

    private ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    private PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(baos);

    private ServletOutputStream sos = new ByteArrayServletStream(baos);

    public PrintWriter getWriter() {
        return pw;
    }

    public ServletOutputStream getStream() {
        return sos;
    }

    byte[] toByteArray() {
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

SwaggerFilter.java

```
public class SwaggerFilter implements Filter {

    final String APPLICATION_XHTML = "application/xhtml";
    final String XML_ELEMENT_START = "<Json>";
    final String XML_ELEMENT_END = "</Json>";

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }

    /**
     * Filter to remove the extra JSON element and render it
     */
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        ByteArrayPrinter pw = new ByteArrayPrinter();

        // Create a wrapper
        HttpServletResponse wrappedResp = new HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) {

            @Override
            public void setContentType(final String type) {
                super.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE);
            }

            @Override
            public PrintWriter getWriter() {
                return pw.getWriter();
            }

            // set the outputstream content type to JSON
            @Override
            public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
                ServletResponse response = this.getResponse();

                String ct = (response != null) ? response.getContentType() : null;
                if (ct != null && ct.contains(APPLICATION_XHTML)) {
                    response.setContentType(ct + AppConstants.CONSTANT_COMMA + MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE);
                }
                return pw.getStream();
            }

        };
        chain.doFilter(httpRequest, wrappedResp);

        byte[] bytes = pw.toByteArray();
        String respBody = new String(bytes);
        if (respBody.startsWith(XML_ELEMENT_START)) {

            // Instead of using substring made use of stream to identify any occurence of <Json> xml element
            List<String> xmlStringList = Stream.of(respBody).filter((s1) -> s1.contains(XML_ELEMENT_START))
                    // filter the string. Split it by mapping to new arraylist by space
                    .map((stringBeforeSplit) -> Arrays.asList(stringBeforeSplit.split(AppConstants.CONSTANT_SPACE)))
                    // create a new stream of array list strings
                    .flatMap((stringArrayAfterSplit) -> {
                        StringBuffer concatenateStringStream = new StringBuffer();
                        stringArrayAfterSplit.forEach(item -> {

                            concatenateStringStream.append(item);

                        });
                        // remove the <JSON> xml element and return the values
                        return Stream
                                .of(concatenateStringStream.toString().trim()
                                        .replace(XML_ELEMENT_START, AppConstants.CONSTANT_NO_SPACE)
                                        .replace(XML_ELEMENT_END, AppConstants.CONSTANT_NO_SPACE));
                        // collect it as a new list of strings with the xmlelement - <JSON> removed
                    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

            // Join the list to make it one
            String finalString = String.join(AppConstants.CONSTANT_NO_SPACE, xmlStringList);

            // write to the outputstream with JSON mediatype
            response.getOutputStream().write(finalString.getBytes());
        } else {
            response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Comment: I have provided this as a part of my own answer in this SO question. I understand that this is somewhat redundant but my usecase was different. For more details, you could check out the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53867077/cannot-write-new-response-in-servlet-filter

Answer (score 0):

Just coding as below to return custom response body with error code

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final ObjectNode root = mapper.createObjectNode();
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);

// set return custom response
ErrorRepsonse error = ErrorRepsonse.builder()
        .status("400")
        .results(List.of(
                ErrorRepsonse.Result.builder()
                        .errorCode("999")
                        .build()
        ))
        .build();
response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
((HttpServletResponse) response).setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
response.getWriter().write(mapper.writeValueAsString(error));
return; // important!!!
```