# How to add ")]}',\n" before each Spring JSON response to prevent common vulnerability

Tags: java, spring, servlets, servlet-filters

I want to add a `")]}',\n"` prefix to all JSON responses produced by servlet in order to prevent JSON vulnerability as [AngularJS suggests](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#security-considerations). I found a [way to modify the response content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736328/looking-for-an-example-for-inserting-content-into-the-response-using-a-servlet-f). Using the `OncePerRequestFilter` base class from Spring, I have end up with:

```
public class JsonArrayVulnerabilityPreventorFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter responseOut = response.getWriter();
        CharResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new CharResponseWrapper(response);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);
        if (StringUtils.contains(responseWrapper.getHeader("Content-Type"), "application/json")) {
            responseOut.write(")]}',\n");
        }
        String originalServletResponse = responseWrapper.toString();
        responseOut.write(originalServletResponse);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I have introduced the response wrapper, the `Content-Type` header (and few others) disappeared from the response. I have confirmed that without a wrapper, the `response.getHeaderNames()` call returns 14 different headers (including content type) whereas with the wrapper, there is only 9. It also breaks character encoding, because with the wrapper the `Content-Type` header does not tell the browser that the content is in UTF-8. Why?

---

Source and idea of the `CharResponseWrapper` [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14736818/878514).

```
public class CharResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
    private CharArrayWriter output;

    public String toString() {
        return output.toString();
    }

    public CharResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
        super(response);
        output = new CharArrayWriter();
    }

    public PrintWriter getWriter() {
        return new PrintWriter(output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I resolved the root problem (adding the `)]}',\n` prefix to every JSON response) with the following configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebappConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setJsonPrefix(")]}',\n");
        converters.add(converter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When using [Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-responsebody-rendering), just having a bean as below would also work.

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setJsonPrefix(")]}',\n");
    return converter;

}
```

[Here](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon/blob/master/src/main/java/com/naturalprogrammer/spring/lemon/LemonAutoConfiguration.java#L109) is an example from the [Spring Lemon](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon) project.