# How to trim Swagger docs based on current User Role in Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

I'm developing application using Spring Boot, and I'm using Swagger to auto-generate API docs and also I use `swagger-ui.html` to interact with those APIs.

I have Spring Security enabled too, and I have Users with different roles. Different REST APIs are available to different roles.

Question: how do I configure Swagger to respect Spring's `@Secured` annotation and trim operations displayed by `swagger-ui.html` so that only operations available to current user are available?

I.e. imagine following controller

```
@RestController
@Secured(ROLE_USER)
public void SomeRestController {
  @GetMapping
  @Secured(ROLE_USER_TOP_MANAGER)
  public String getInfoForTopManager() { /*...*/ }

  @GetMapping
  @Secured(ROLE_USER_MIDDLE_MANAGER)
  public String getInfoForMiddleManager() { /*...*/ }

  @GetMapping
  public String getInfoForAnyUser() { /*...*/ }
}
```

Swagger will show both operations `getInfoForTopManager` and `getInfoForMiddleManager` regardless of current user role. In case currently authenticated user role is `ROLE_USER_MIDDLE_MANAGER`, I want only `getInfoForMiddleManager` and `getInfoForAnyUser` operations to be available in the Swagger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I think found good solution to that question. Solution consists of 2 parts:

1. Extend controllers scanning logic through `OperationBuilderPlugin` to retain roles in the Swagger's vendor extensions
2. Override `ServiceModelToSwagger2MapperImpl` bean to filter out actions based on current security context

In your project this might look a bit different (i.e. most likely you don't have thing like `securityContextResolver`), but I believe you'll get the gist of this solution from following code:

**Part 1: Extend controllers scanning logic to retain roles in the Swagger's vendor extensions**

```
@Component
@Order(SwaggerPluginSupport.SWAGGER_PLUGIN_ORDER + 1000)
public class OperationBuilderPluginSecuredAware implements OperationBuilderPlugin {
    @Override
    public void apply(OperationContext context) {
        Set<String> roles = new HashSet<>();
        Secured controllerAnnotation = context.findControllerAnnotation(Secured.class).orNull();
        if (controllerAnnotation != null) {
            roles.addAll(List.of(controllerAnnotation.value()));
        }

        Secured methodAnnotation = context.findAnnotation(Secured.class).orNull();
        if (methodAnnotation != null) {
            roles.addAll(List.of(methodAnnotation.value()));
        }

        if (!roles.isEmpty()) {
            context.operationBuilder().extensions(List.of(new TrimToRoles(roles.toArray(new String[0]))));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(DocumentationType delimiter) {
        return SwaggerPluginSupport.pluginDoesApply(delimiter);
    }
}
```

**Part 2: Filter out actions based on current security context**

```
@Primary
@Component
public class ServiceModelToSwagger2MapperImplEx extends ServiceModelToSwagger2MapperImpl {
    @Autowired
    private SecurityContextResolver<User> securityContextResolver;

    @Override
    protected io.swagger.models.Operation mapOperation(Operation from) {
        if (from == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (!isPermittedForCurrentUser(findTrimToRolesExtension(from.getVendorExtensions()))) {
            return null;
        }
        return super.mapOperation(from);
    }

    private boolean isPermittedForCurrentUser(TrimToRoles trimToRoles) {
        if (trimToRoles == null) {
            return true;
        }
        if (securityContextResolver.hasAnyRole(trimToRoles.getValue())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private TrimToRoles findTrimToRolesExtension(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") List<VendorExtension> list) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list)) {
            return null;
        }
        return list.stream().filter(x -> x instanceof TrimToRoles).map(TrimToRoles.class::cast).findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, Path> mapApiListings(Multimap<String, ApiListing> apiListings) {
        Map<String, Path> paths = super.mapApiListings(apiListings);
        return paths.entrySet().stream().filter(x -> !x.getValue().isEmpty())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getKey(), v -> v.getValue()));
    }

    @Override
    public Swagger mapDocumentation(Documentation from) {
        Swagger ret = super.mapDocumentation(from);
        Predicate<? super Tag> hasAtLeastOneOperation = tag -> ret.getPaths().values().stream()
                .anyMatch(x -> x.getOperations().stream().anyMatch(y -> y.getTags().contains(tag.getName())));
        ret.setTags(ret.getTags().stream().filter(hasAtLeastOneOperation).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        return ret;
    }
}
```

p.s. these impls are not efficient, but given their usage scenarios I preferred simple impl