# Whether it is necessary for us to close OutputStream created in HttpServletResponseWrapper

Tags: java, outputstream

I want to implement a java interface `HttpServletResponseWrapper` and I got an answer in StackOverflow ([Looking for an example for inserting content into the response using a servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736328/looking-for-an-example-for-inserting-content-into-the-response-using-a-servlet-f))
in this answer we create a `ByteArrayPrintWriter`, but in this code why we don't close the `ByteArrayPrintWriter` stream, is there any problem in this way? thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case it's not necessary to close the `ByteArrayOutputStream` since  we know the internal implementation has no buffers or anything that would require a `close()` call. The bytes are written to the backing array directly, and closing is a `NO-OP`.

```
/**
 * Closing a <tt>ByteArrayOutputStream</tt> has no effect. The methods in
 * this class can be called after the stream has been closed without
 * generating an <tt>IOException</tt>.
 */
public void close() throws IOException {
}
```

It might be a good idea to still call `close()` for consistency's sake, but that's your choice. Either way is fine.