# How to convert the body of a HttpServletResponse output stream to String

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

I'd like to modify the response object of type `HttpServletResponse`, I've implemented the filter which extends `OncePerrequestFilter` base class.

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) {
    os = response.getOutputStream();
}
```

I'd like to get the response as `String`, modifying it and updating the HttpServletRequest instance content with my modified `String`. It is possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for an example for inserting content into the response using a servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14736328/looking-for-an-example-for-inserting-content-into-the-response-using-a-servlet-f)

Comment: Nope, I'm trying to use Httpservletresponse and the link you have is using servlertresponse

Comment: Here CharResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new CharResponseWrapper(
            (HttpServletResponse) response); they cast the response to HttpServletResponse, I think the only difference is that you don't need the cast